# Count occurences of integers starting with 4 in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
        index              client_ip  http_response_code
                                                                                    
2022-07-23 05:10:10+00:00  172.19.0.1     300   
2022-07-23 06:13:26+00:00  192.168.0.1    400
          ...                 ...         ...
```

I need to group by `clientip` and count the number of occurences of number 4xx in the column `response`, namely the times of occurences of integers start with 4.

What I have tried is the following:

```
df.groupby('client_ip')['http_response_code'].apply(lambda x: (str(x).startswith(str(4))).sum())
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

However, if let's say that I need to find the number of occurences of 400, then the following does not give any error, although is still boolean:

```
df.groupby('client_ip')['http_response_code'].apply(lambda x: (x==400).sum())
```

Any idea of what is wrong here?

Comment: the function apply to each element, you want to sum over all the array after the function is applied: sum(f.groupby('client_ip')['http_response_code'].apply(lambda x: (str(x).startswith(str(4)))) or something like that

Comment: Why don't you filter the data frame first before grouping it? Like `df[df["response"].astype(str).str.startswith("4")].groupby(["clientip"])["response"].count()`

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproductible example, with a datafrrame as a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea of what is wrong here?

Your function get Series as input, comparing it against value gives Series of boolean values, which could be summed, using `str` functions gives str, which has not `.sum`. Use `.astype(str)` to convert each value into str rather than whole Series, example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"User":["A","A","B"],"Status":[400,301,302]})
grouped = df.groupby("User")["Status"].apply(lambda x:x.astype(str).str.startswith("4").sum())
print(grouped)
```

output

```
User
A    1
B    0
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'client_id': np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=10, replace=True, p=None), 'http_response_code': np.random.choice([300, 400], size=10, replace=True, p=None)})
print(df[df.http_response_code.apply(lambda x: (str(x).startswith(str(4))))].groupby('client_id').count())
```

Dataframe:

```
   client_id  http_response_code
0          3                 300
1          2                 400
2          3                 300
3          3                 400
4          1                 300
5          3                 400
6          3                 400
7          2                 300
8          3                 300
9          2                 300
```

Result:

```
           http_response_code
client_id                    
2                           1
3                           3
```